# Использование косвенного невиртуального базового класса не допускается

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, конструктор

Есть родительский класс being, есть дочерний monsterlike, есть дочерний класс образовавшийся от этого дочернего ogr. Для переменных в род. классе создан конструктор чтобы можно было их инициализировать в дочерних классах, чтобы не повторять их каждый раз. С 1-м доч. классом та же история. Однако в 2-м доч. клас. возникла ошибка с конструктором род. класса. При этом с конструктором 1-го доч. класса всё в порядке. Спросил у знакомого опытного программиста, он сказал "присваивай значения только в главном классе, а в доч. просто подставляй под них всё что нужно". Но мне кажется это не то что мне нужно, да и сомневаюсь что так будет удобно для дальнейшего исп. программы.

being.h

```
class being
{
protected:
    std::string Name;
public:
    being();
    being(int S, int E, int I, int D, float HP, float MR, float PR, float AD, bool DTP);
    int strength;
    int endurance;
    int intelligence;
    int dexterity;
    float healthPoint;
    float magicResist;
    float physicalResist;
    float atackDamage;
    bool damageTypePhysical = true;
    void atack(being &being);
    void defense();
};
```

monsterlike.h

```
#include "Being.h"
#include "Humanlike.h"
class monsterlike : public being 
{
public:
    monsterlike() : being(15, 10, 5, 8, 100, 15, 25, 25, true) {}
    monsterlike(int M, int A);
    int minions = 0;
    int animanlIstinct = 10;;
    void scream(humanlike &humanlike); 
    void rabies(humanlike &humalike);  
};
```

org.h (здесь being подсвечивается красным и выдает соответствующую ошибку)

```
#include "Monsterlike.h"
class ogr : public monsterlike
{
public:
    ogr() : being(15, 10, 5, 8, 100, 15, 25, 25, true) {}
    ogr() : monsterlike(3, 30) {}
};
```

Comment: Что? Ещё раз прочитал, ничего не понял... Какую соответствующую ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что у вас

```
ogr() : being(15, 10, 5, 8, 100, 15, 25, 25, true) {}
ogr() : monsterlike(3, 30) {}
```

два конструктора по умолчанию, с одинаковой сигнатурой. Компилятор с ума сойдет...

Далее - "вассал моего вассала - не мой вассал" :) - вы должны в конструкторе `org()` сконструировать предка, а не дедушку. Дедушку будет конструировать предок. Так что тут достаточно вместо первого конструктора написать

```
ogr() : monsterlike() {}
```

или даже

```
ogr() {}
```

потому что в этом случае у вас все равно будет вызван конструктор предка по умолчанию. А этот конструктор предка по умолчанию как раз и вызывает нужный вам конструктор своего предка:

```
monsterlike() : being(15, 10, 5, 8, 100, 15, 25, 25, true) {}
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Если вставляю ogr() : monsterlike() {}, то вызывается конструктор по умолчанию со значениями из monsterlike. Но что если мне требуется изменить значения переменных этого конструктора для ogr.h?

Comment: Вы можете работать только с предком. С более далекими предками - это надо множественное виртуальное наследование. Сделайте у предка конструктор с кучей параметров, которые просто передаются его предку. Примерно так.